# How to check how many issues are opened daily in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data from issues in a table with the following schema.

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS issues (
  id int,
  created_at DATE,
  deleted_at DATE
);

INSERT INTO issues VALUES
(1, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'),
(2, '2020-01-02', '2020-01-05'),
(3, '2020-01-04', '2020-01-03'),
(4, '2020-01-04', '2020-01-07'),
(5, '2020-01-04', '2020-01-07');
```

I want to know how many issues are open every day using PostgreSQL. We consider an issue being open at date x if:

- `x >= created_at`
- `x <= deleted_at`

There may be days where no issues were created or deleted, as in the example. How can I do the query to obtain how many issues are open every day?

Comment: Personal note on how to do it with bigquery: select * 
from issues
cross join  unnest(
    generate_date_array(
        issues.date_created_at, 
        issues.date_last_modified
    )
) as date_dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method uses `generate_series()`:

```
select gs.dte, count(*)
from issues i cross join lateral
     generate_series(i.created_at, i.deleted_at, interval '1 day') gs(dte)
group by gs.dte
order by gs.dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=77f96bebf14a2e0be96bd53a4647b464) is a db<>fiddle.

The above skips dates with no issues.  One way to fix this would be to generate all dates and then:

```
select gs.dte, count(i.id)
from (select min(created_at) as first_date, max(deleted_at) as last_date
      from issues i
     ) m cross join lateral
     generate_series(m.first_date, m.last_date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) left join
     issues i
     on gs.dte >= i.created_at and gs.dte <= i.deleted_at
group by gs.dte
order by gs.dte;
```

However, the first method should be more efficient if this is not necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "it skips dates"?

Comment: Don't they give the same results in all circumstances?

Comment: @DavidMasip . . . No.  The first query will miss dates that have no issues.  I am guessing that is not an "issue" and it should have better performance than the second query.